# System.Drawing.FontFamily.GetGdipGenericSansSerif() : Font '?' cannot be found

Tags: c#

I've been having this issue for a while now and I have absolutely no idea how to resolve it. So I am calling

```
this.console = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
```

and am getting the error

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Font '?' cannot be found.'
```

Here is the call stack

```
System.Drawing.FontFamily.GetGdipGenericSansSerif() in FontFamily.cs
System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericSansSerif.get() in FontFamily.cs
System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont.get() in SystemFonts.cs
System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefaultFont.get()
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Font.get()
System.Windows.Forms.Control.FontHeight.get()
System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.PreferredHeight.get()
System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.DefaultSize.get()
System.Windows.Forms.Control.Control(bool)
System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.TextBoxBase()
```

Please send help, it just doesn't work :/

Comment: What is `this.console`?

Comment: Sounds like permissions for the Windows "Fonts" folder (C:\Windows\Fonts) might be messed up.

Comment: Any ideas on fixing it? this.console is just a variable holding the textbox